# Transit Time in Brussels

Tags: transit, short-connections, brussels, bru

My flight from the US is scheduled to arrive in Brussels at 8:45 am and the connecting flight to Amsterdam is at 10:35 am.  They are on separate tickets, so I probably need to go through Immigration and Customs.  I have carry on only.  Is that enough time?

Answer (score 1):

Check FlightRadar24 or FlightAware whether your US flight usually arrives on time.

It can be possible:

- If the terminal is the same one.
- If your US plain arrives on time.
- If you checked-in online for the next flight. In such a case, you can use a quicker Transfer route.
- If you are in good shape and can run or go faster when you need it.

Advice:

- Become familiar with the airport. Find a map on the Internet
- Be ready to ask people in the queue to let you go (in case you have a few time and a long queue during immigration or security)